# sitemap.xml URL limitations and alternate links for i18n

Tags: sitemap, sitemap.xml

I am building the `sitemap.xml` file for my Web site, and I take into account [Google's indications](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap) about the limitations of these files:

> **Sitemap size limits**: All formats limit a single sitemap to 50MB
> (uncompressed) or 50,000 URLs. If you have a larger file or more URLs,
> you must break your sitemap into multiple sitemaps.

On my website I have implemented internationalization so for each URL I have 3 alternative versions available (English, Spanish and French). This I have translated it in the `sitemap.xml` in the following way for each URL:

```
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/contact</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/contact" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en/contact" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://example.com/es/contact" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://example.com/fr/contact" />
</url>
```

My question is: does this URL with its variants count as **1 URL** or as **5 different URLs** (regarding to the number of links I have written)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you then have separate `<loc>` for each language?

Comment: No. I have 1 `<loc>` for each page, and then there are several languages defined, as the example show

Comment: Each language is a separate page.  You should have a `<loc>` for each language.

Comment: Their example shows separate `<loc>`s for each URL that is listed as a `rel=alternate`.  It also says "Create a separate `<url>` element for each URL"

Comment: You're right, I'll read it again carefully. Thanks!